# Adding operations in the middle of a complex sequence diagram in Visio 2003

Tags: microsoft-visio, uml

I am using Microsoft Visio 2003 to define static classes with operations/methods and a sequence diagrams referring to these classes. The sequence diagram is almost done, but I realized that I missed one operation in the middle of the diagram. When I try to move the rest of the sequences down by selecting them as a block, all the operations in the block lose their links with the static diagrams. (Methods which referred to static classes that appeared as fun() in sequence diagram, after movement appear as fun in sequence diagram, which means that now they no longer refer to static diagrams and any future changes would not be reflected in dynamic sequence diagrams automatically.)

The sequence diagrams have grown to A3 size paper and I have many such diagrams which need correction. Manually moving the operations one by one would involve lots of effort. Could someone kindly suggest a way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have spent time trying to figure this out, and have concluded that there is no solution for this. We need to manually move each operations in sequence down to make way for inserting even one new operation in Visio. Not sure if other enterprise suite products like Rational Rose and EA has any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://sequencediagram.org/
It provides much more capabilities than any other sequence diagraming tool
I like it a lot

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).